# Fixed top div and bottom scrollable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to create two `div` elements on top of each other ?

I want to create a website of one page, where there is two `div` elements on top of each other:

```
1- the one on top  --> fixed 

2- the one on bottom --> scrollable
```

Thank you, I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

Its very simple !!

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0px auto;
  font-family: Calibri, Georgia, Ubuntu-C;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 20PX
}
#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: skyblue;
  position: fixed;
}
#content {
  height: 750px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  background: ORANGE;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">

</div>

<div id="content">

</div>
```

Comment: Good solution but add some explanation to the code since OP seems to be a newbie.

Answer (score 1):

Try this https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/74/

HTML

```
<div class="fixed">Fixed</div>
<div class="scroll">Scroll</div>
```

CSS

```
.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    background: blue;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    top: 0;
    color: white;
}

.scroll {
    height: 1000px;
    width: 100%;
    background: green;
    color: white;
    padding-top:50px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

css:

```
* {margin: 0 auto;}
body {
    width:100%;
    heighT:100%;
    position: fixed;
}
#header {
    width: 100%; /* Any Width you want */
    height: 20%;  /* Any Height you want */
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
}
#content {
    width:100%;   /* Any Width you want */
    height:80%;   /* Any Height you want */
    overflow: auto;
    margin-top: 20%; /* It should be the same with your #header height */
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Just one point, The Sum of the height of your content div and header div should be 100%.

Answer (score -3):

I am not sure if this is what you meant with your question but basically this is a div on top of the other and one of them is scrollable.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt">
<html>
   <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>demo</title>
        <style>
            .fixedDiv{
                width:250px; 
                height: 400px;
                padding: 10px;
                background-color: #FF0000;
               }
        .scrollDiv{
            position:relative; 
            top:100px; 
            width:100%;
            height:73%;
            overflow-y: auto;
        } 

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="fixedDiv">
        <div class="scrollDiv">
            Maecenas dignissim, nunc sit amet accumsan fermentum, neque neque sagittis lorem, id auctor massa ipsum vel ligula. Curabitur molestie nunc vel lorem feugiat faucibus. Donec sit amet auctor sapien. Cras sed metus eget ligula imperdiet eleifend id sed enim. Nulla lacinia nulla a tortor suscipit malesuada non non nulla. Nulla non iaculis tortor. Sed mi diam, interdum ut purus sed, sodales viverra ex. Mauris nisl est, tristique ut elit ac, hendrerit hendrerit nibh. Praesent ligula urna, condimentum nec maximus a, blandit sit amet velit. Ut auctor sodales justo at vehicula. Ut tristique est feugiat ligula dignissim, vel ornare massa fermentum. Donec lacinia, odio eget ullamcorper fringilla, magna quam ullamcorper augue, vel faucibus libero arcu quis arcu. Vivamus sollicitudin sem sapien, ut dignissim ex volutpat a. Donec neque enim, faucibus id facilisis nec, feugiat accumsan lorem.
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```